# No se escucha muy claramente

Tags: españa, pronunciación, dialectos

Necesito ayuda con [-2:02 a -1:57](https://www.rtve.es/play/audios/en-dias-como-hoy/robo-bebes-durante-fue-practica-mas-perversa-dictadura-argentina/1456153/). Creo que dice algo como "Esa justicia de la puerta seguir investigando y a poder resolvar 400 casos de robados que..." pero no tiene mucho sentido. Parece tener un acento castellano muy fuerte. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En rigor, tu pregunta debería haber sido: No se oye muy bien/claro. "Escuchar" es una acción voluntaria, mientras que "oír" es involuntaria. Por más que escuchaste atentamente, no oíste bien. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Esa justicia abre la puerta a seguir investigando y a poder resolver 400 casos de bebés robados que aún esperan respuesta, Fran."